# array_merge error during seeder whilst loading eloquent data

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

## Synopsis

I have ran into a very confusing problem with [laravel-5](/questions/tagged/laravel-5). Essentially what I have are a number of seeders which loads data from a JSON document and inserts into the database using [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) - this works fine.

I have a final seeder which loops through some data, during this loop I load a record using  but the moment I try to access the data I receive the following error:

```
  [ErrorException]                            
    array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
```

## Seeder Snippet

```
foreach ($data as $country => $states) {
    $countryId = Country::where('iso2_code', $country)->first()->pluck('id');

    dd($countryId); // ErrorException

    array_walk($states, function (&$value) use ($countryId) {
        $value = ['country_id' => $countryId, 'name' => $value];
    });

    State::insert($states);
}
```

The confusing part about this error is if I do not use Eloquent my problem is solved, as per:

```
foreach ($data as $country => $states) {
    $countryId = DB::table((new Country)->getTable())
        ->select('id')
        ->where('iso2_code', $country)
        ->first();

    dd($countryId->id); // Works.

    array_walk($states, function (&$value) use ($countryId) {
        $value = ['country_id' => $countryId, 'name' => $value];
    });

    State::insert($states);
}
```

Why is it then that `DB` works as expected but `Eloquent` triggers some array_merge error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Solution

In my situation I was setting `protected $dates = false` on my model.  Where typically as per the documentation I should be using `public $timestamps = false` or `protected $dates = array();`.